Merge / Join dataframes in R
I know there are a lot of posts regarding merges and joins already, but I have tried every version and can't seem to figure out how to get what I want. I am creating a Shiny dashboard with some value boxes. I have simplified / sanitized my code and data for this post, so I know it might now make a lot of sense. My data looks like this:
Department,FY,Total
Accounting,22,0
Analysis,22,22
Analysis,24,22
Marketing,24,10")

The value boxes that I am generating come out like this:

I am trying to make the value boxes show a 0 rather than just be blank if data is not available for a particular department. I thought I could initialize all of the Department's mean values to 0 and then merge the df containing the initialization values with the one containing the actual data, but it is not working. I have tried each of the joins / merges and can't get exactly what I need. Here is my code:
initialDept_df <- data.frame(Department=c('Engineering','Analysis','Test'),
                            Mean=c(0, 0, 0))
Department_df <- dplyr::full_join(workEfforts_df, initialDept_df)

This gives me this for Department_df which is closer than any of the other merge / joins I have tried:
Department,Mean
Analysis,22
Engineering,0
Analysis,0
Test,0

What I really need is the first Analysis line = 22, and then all the other departments set to 0. Can anyone tell me how to get this done? Thanks!
I'm adding this section to try to make it more clear what I need. I have 2 data frames, one is initializing all the Mean values to 0 and is called initialDept_df. It looks like this:
Department,Mean
Engineering,0
Analysis,0
Test,0

The second data frame is called Department_df and it looks like this:
Department,Mean
Analysis,22

I want to merge both of these data frames so that the final result looks like this:
Department,Mean
Engineering,0
Analysis,22
Test,0


Do the join then replace the NA values with 0, workEfforts_df %>% filter(FY==22) %>% right_join(initialDept_df) %>% mutate(Total = tidyr::replace_na(Total, 0)) or maybe workEfforts_df %>% summarize(Total=mean(Total), .by=Department) %>% right_join(initialDept_df) %>% mutate(Total = tidyr::replace_na(Total, 0)). It's not clear exactly what you wanted to happen

I tried your suggestions, and I do get 0 values now in my value boxes, but I lost the 22 for Analysis. I may have not implemented correctly, but I edited my question to try to make it more clear what I need. Thanks!

I figured out a way to get what I want. It is probably not the best way, but it works. I did a group_by Department on the Department_df data frame, arrange the rows in descending order by the Mean column and then use slice to get the first row for each Department which gets rid of the 0 rows if data exists for a department.
